# expressJS and socket.io listening to different ports and socket.io client connect

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So I have a nodejs application which uses socket.io and expressjs

I use port '3000' for the express app and port '8080' for the socket app

1. Is it possible to use the same port for both these services?(express and socket.io)
2. When i want to connect to a socket from the client, I use the following code:

   var socket = io('http://localhost:8080')

whats the right way of connecting to it( I see various ways in tutorials across the internet) and have no clue.

Comment: I don't if it can help but you might wanna check this similar issue with answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198835/socket-io-404-error/48255983#48255983

Comment: try turning off your mamp or xampp

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the same port for both these services?(express and socket.io)

yes

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080); //or 3000
```

> When i want to connect to a socket from the client, I use the following code:

At the front end :

include `socket.io` lib

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); //or 3000
</script>
```

EDIT : 
without express

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(8080);
```

For more info [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/docs/)

Comment: Do I need to use the http module for socket.io or can I use express?

Comment: For socket you need install socket.io and for express you need it  express

Comment: var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);.                                    I meant that. Do I need to require the http module ? It can I use 'var up=require ('socket.io').(app)